# Access private methods of superclass in Swift

Tags: swift, swift2

I would like to use private members and methods of superclass in its subclass, still don't want them to be visible on instance level. Well, I think there is no such possibility in Swift since it has only private/internal/public access modifiers. But maybe some workaround?

I heard about popular in other languages protected modifier, but it actually doing opposite of mine point. Is there no such possibility in all languages? Am I doing something wrong if I often need this thing in my subclass hierarchy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a subclass access its superclass's private members BUT it has to be in the same file as the super class.  Privacy applies outside the file. Anything within a file can access private members. This is not intuitive.  Here is a simple playground to demonstrate. Since `Bar` is declared in the same file, it can access `Foo`'s `private x` member.
[image]

from *Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.1)*, **Access Levels**, "Private access restricts the use of an entity to its own file."